# No puedo generar mi apk en Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android

Antes de actualizar android studio mi apk la generaba correctamente, ahora desde la versión 4.1 me da el siguiente error:

> Task :app:compressReleaseAssets FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:compressReleaseAssets'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> S:\WORKS\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\release\out

Los archivos no tuvieron cambios desde antes de la actualización.

Comment: ¿Estas firmado y generando el .apk o solo tratas de subir el apk a tu dispositivo?

Answer (score 0):

Luego de publicar, lei https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333649/what-is-navigation-json-in-android-studio-4-1
y probé haciendo un downgrade de Android Gradle Plugin version de 4.1.0 a 4.0.2 y el Gradle version de 6.5 a 6.4.1 y funcionó perfecto.

Comment: Hacer un Downgrade en realidad no es una solución.